# how to learn frameworks of android

Tags: android, frameworks

i want to learn modify and  compile source, what i need to learn,can you give some link
or sample and so on, i know  i also need to learn  frameworks knowledge,how and where to learn

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I learn Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475152/how-can-i-learn-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the source from source.android.com and start doing things with it.
Provided that you have a super system with monster resources, you can play with the source.

And regarding changes, so there are various things inside the source, like lots of XML files, lots of images, drawables..
Lots Java code and C code too.
You might need to modify the drivers and the kernels too.
There's only one compiled source of info, that is the android documentation itself, but is a little buggy.
apart from this, you can ask google about the problems.

all in all, I didn't find any resource, during my work, that serves as the sole source of information.
since you see lots of resources, so collective knowledge of all of them will help you in the end.

This area is still quite poorly documented.
But things should be comprehensible, and understandable as you keep working with it.

Comment: thank you for your answer.about modify the drivers and the kernels ,the documentation is quite poorly,can you recommend some link or blog

Comment: Yes, Document is quite poor. And since I am back on the SDK and have sadly lost all the links, but in my work, I always used to rely on Google Brother, i.e. dig my way out by searching for solutions everytime I was in a fix.
Kernel and Driver modification must very much like all the other Kernel and Driver modifications. and there would be some dedicated site/blog/forum for it. I am leaving you on your own brother, sorry for that! :-P